# How Can i integrate a Google Login Method in PHP Application?

Tags: php

How can i integrate a google login Method to my PHP Application?
how can i work with that?what i mean is how my program will understand this is a particular user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation for Federated Login using the Google OpenID API: http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OpenID.html

Also, here is a link to a PHP class that you can use as a gateway to the API: http://www.andrewpeace.com/php-google-login-class.html

Comment: I am also not familiar with Zend ;).thats why i asked if it is with Zend, if so i cant use that for my educational purpose